# Merge htaccess HTTP_HOST Rewrite Cond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have this htaccess conditions...

```
# changed... subdomains to subdirectories...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^acoruna.domain\.es [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.es/acoruna/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alava.domain\.es [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.es/alava/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^albacete.domain\.es [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.es/albacete/$1 [R=301,L]
# changed... subdomains to subdirectories...
```

My question is,, can i merge all that RewriteCond & Rewrite Rules, in only 1? because all do the same.

Thanks, regards from Spain.

Comment: You can capture the subdomain part in a RewriteCond with a regular expression, and then reference that in your RewriteRule, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.es/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```